# Remember some information and reflect them in the ToC

Tags: macros, table-of-contents

I wish to store some information (e.g. value of a macro) each time a `\section` is called, so that these data can be used when ToC is build. For example, suppose I define a macro `\SomeInfo` and use it to store the name of color. And the document goes like this:

```
\renewcommand{\SomeInfo}{blue!50!cyan}
\section{BLUE}
...

\renewcommand{\SomeInfo}{green!60!black}
\section{GREEN}
...

\renewcommand{\SomeInfo}{red}
\section{RED}
...
```

Then I wish each value of `\SomeInfo` can be recorded somewhere, and with these information to build a table of contents like this:

[image]

Is this possible? If so, how can one achieve this?

Below is a MWE, I have included a ToC setting using `titletoc`, trying to use this `\SomeInfo`. Of course, this won't work for now, because only the current value is available, the past values have been forgotten.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\SomeInfo{black}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}
    [2em]
    {\bfseries\color{\SomeInfo}} % of course this won't work
    {\contentslabel{2em}}
    {\hspace*{-2em}}
    {\hfill\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%% Desired result, hard coded
% \noindent
% {\Large\bfseries Contents}\medskip\\
% {\color{blue!50!cyan}\bfseries 1~~\,BLUE\hfill 1}\medskip\\
% {\color{green!60!black}\bfseries 2~~\,GREEN\hfill 1}\medskip\\
% {\color{red}\bfseries 3~~\,RED\hfill 1}

\renewcommand{\SomeInfo}{blue!50!cyan}
\section{BLUE}
...

\renewcommand{\SomeInfo}{green!60!black}
\section{GREEN}
...

\renewcommand{\SomeInfo}{red}
\section{RED}
...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must pass the redefinition of the color to the  `toc` file, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{sectiontoccolor}{black}
\newcommand*{\setsectiontoccolor}[1]{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\colorlet{sectiontoccolor}{#1}}%
}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}%
    [2em]%
    {\bfseries\color{sectiontoccolor}}%
    {\contentslabel{2em}}%
    {\hspace*{-2em}}%
    {\hfill\contentspage}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setsectiontoccolor{blue!50!cyan}
\section{BLUE}

\setsectiontoccolor{green!60!black}
\section{GREEN}

\setsectiontoccolor{red}
\section{RED}

\section{STILL RED}

\setsectiontoccolor{black}
\section{BLACK AGAIN}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! I have one question: how can I pass the value of a command to another in this `\addtocontents`? For example, if I have one command `\SomeInfo` whose value may be changed, and another temporary command `\TempInfo` to store the current value. I'd like to do something like  `\addtocontents{toc}{\renewcommand{\TempInfo}{\SomeInfo}}`, but it is the text "`\SomeInfo`" being written into the toc file, not its value. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: @Jinwen `\addtocontents` (like all writes) expands its arguments. If you want to pass a control sequence which should be expanded only when the toc file is read then use `\protect` in front of it (as I've done above). So `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\TempInfo}{\SomeInfo}}` will write to the toc with the current meaning of `\SomeInfo`, while `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\TempInfo}{\protect\SomeInfo}}` will write the line as is.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\nsect}[2]{\addtocontents{toc}{\color{#1}}%
\section{#2}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\color{black}}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\nsect{blue}{My first section}
\nsect{green}{My second}
\nsect{red}{Third}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: I think this means that the `\color{color}` command will still be active until the next time you change it.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes. I thought that the OP wanted a new color at each new section.

Comment: I agree that it would have been helpful for OP to better explain what they wanted.  But if your TOC comes before the rest of the document, then the last color will still be active when the first section starts.

Comment: @Teepeemm Very nice point. I have edited the answer. Still quick and dirty though.